# Make View slide on screen from outside of parent

Tags: android, android-animation

Let's say that I want to make a `TranslateAnimation` on one View to slide in on screen. Everything looks fine if we have one parent layout which and for example button inside that layout. Then `TranslateAnimation` is easily defined at button would always appear from 'outside' of screen.

The problem is if we have situation like this:

```
<LinearLayout1>
  ... other layouts, views ...
  <LinearLayout2>
    <button></button>
  </LinearLayout2>
  ... other layouts, views ...
</LinearLayout1>
```

The problem is that button is inside LinearLayout2 which is inside LinearLayout1. That means I can make `TranslateAnimation` work only inside LinearLayout2. I can't make button appear from outside of screen because LinearLayout2 take only piece of screen and button cannot be animated from outside of it's parent.

Would it be possible to accomplish animation to appear from outside of screen in this case? Thanks!

Comment: "...button cannot be animated from outside of it's parent." - Are you sure about that? I mean, have you tried it out? I'm just asking because I'm pretty sure I've done that before.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly have a view animate in from outside of its parent. I don't know about animating in from outside of its grandparent, however. I haven't tried it, but I think the view would get clipped to only be drawn within its parent.

Here is some code for animating a view up from the bottom of its parent view:

```
TranslateAnimation a = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,  // from X
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0,  // to X
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1f, // from Y
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0); // to Y
a.setDuration(1000); // milliseconds
button.startAnimation(a);
```

Is LinearLayout2 near a screen edge? Could you just animate the button in from that side of the parent, so it seems to come from outside the screen?